# How to change the color of the widget center ‘Add Widget’ button

Tags: ios, swift, widget, ios14, widgetkit

[image]
[image]

Some apps have changed the color of the ‘Add Widget’ button. How can I change the color of the button?

Answer (score 12):

Useful to know as from [WWDC Notes](https://www.wwdcnotes.com/notes/wwdc20/10194/) `WidgetBackground` will also affect other areas of widget, like color of flipped widget during editing for `Intent` based widgets.

[image: Widget Colors]

Answer (score 8):

Change the color of `WidgetBackground` in `Assets.xcassets`.

Comment: this can be comment

Comment: @NayanDave if it provides a proper solution to the problem, an answer is fine.